# Solidity bytes32 to JS string?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, javascript

There been a couple of questions on `bytes32` to `string` in solidity itself.  What's the best way to convert a solidity `bytes32` return value to a `string` in JS?

Answer (score 2):

you'll have a good live example of what you want in the browser-solidity, 
especially in line 395 of universal-dapp.js

```
// decode data
                    var decodedObj = EthJS.ABI.rawDecode(outputTypes, result.vm.return);

                    // format decoded data
                    decodedObj = EthJS.ABI.stringify(outputTypes, decodedObj);
```